# Firebase implementing google and facebook sign in on same page

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement google and facebook sign up on same page but I am unable to do that I did lot of google but couldn't find the answer.

Can anybody please provide me sample of google and facebook sign up implemented on same page?

Comment: if you are in android, use firebase-ui library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using FirebaseUI. You can reffer to https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/tree/master/demo/
It takes care of all the edge cases for you at a same time it's straightforward to use.

Also Check Firebase dashboard auth settings as there are situations where for example you sign-in with Google and then sign in with Facebook both using the same email. Account linking would be needed to merge both accounts.

Answer (score 2):

This is complicated issue we've solved a few month ago.
You have to merge your accounts based on different credentials people signed up. You could merge credentials you get from Google/Facebook with already signed in account. If u dont plan provide any other choice to sign in except Google/Facebook, only one options to do this is allowing Multiple Accounts with same Email Address from console.

Comment: Hey I don't want to link authentication provider but to use them on same page and after implementing I found them unclicable  you can check it at 
Link 
http://iitm.000webhostapp.com/login.php

Comment: Have you tried implement just one provider? Did it work for you?
If yes, then just consider which function would you use for sign in, now you have two the same name functions.

Comment: No I will be logged in one account but want to provide my users with 2-3 options to login and login them that best suits them

Comment: Did u try to do that? If u didnt, then try. You should go from simple to complex solution.

Comment: Yes they all are working separately but are not working together

Comment: maybe because you have the same name of the functions implementing that? Try to do everything in the same function and avoid duplicity in var names. Download some IDE for web/js development, Visual Code or WebStorm

Answer (score 1):

This example works with Angular/Ionic.
You need two buttons in HTML:

```
<button ion-button outline (click)="loginWithFacebook()">
    <svg ngClass="svgIcon-use" width="25" height="25" viewBox="0 0 25 25">
      <path d="M21 12.646C21 7.65 16.97 3.6 12 3.6s-9 4.05-9 9.046a9.026 9.026 0 0 0 7.59 8.924v-6.376H8.395V12.64h2.193v-1.88c0-2.186 1.328-3.375 3.267-3.375.93 0 1.728.07 1.96.1V9.77H14.47c-1.055 0-1.26.503-1.26 1.242v1.63h2.517l-.33 2.554H13.21V21.6c4.398-.597 7.79-4.373 7.79-8.954"></path>
    </svg>
  Facebook
</button>

<button ion-button outline (click)="loginWithGoogle()">
    <svg ngClass="svgIcon-use" width="25" height="25" viewBox="0 0 25 25">
      <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <path d="M20.66 12.693c0-.603-.054-1.182-.155-1.738H12.5v3.287h4.575a3.91 3.91 0 0 1-1.697 2.566v2.133h2.747c1.608-1.48 2.535-3.65 2.535-6.24z"
          fill="#4285F4"></path>
        <path d="M12.5 21c2.295 0 4.22-.76 5.625-2.06l-2.747-2.132c-.76.51-1.734.81-2.878.81-2.214 0-4.088-1.494-4.756-3.503h-2.84v2.202A8.498 8.498 0 0 0 12.5 21z"
          fill="#34A853"></path>
        <path d="M7.744 14.115c-.17-.51-.267-1.055-.267-1.615s.097-1.105.267-1.615V8.683h-2.84A8.488 8.488 0 0 0 4 12.5c0 1.372.328 2.67.904 3.817l2.84-2.202z"
          fill="#FBBC05"></path>
        <path d="M12.5 7.38c1.248 0 2.368.43 3.25 1.272l2.437-2.438C16.715 4.842 14.79 4 12.5 4a8.497 8.497 0 0 0-7.596 4.683l2.84 2.202c.668-2.01 2.542-3.504 4.756-3.504z"
          fill="#EA4335"></path>
      </g>
    </svg>
  Google
</button>
```

Login.ts

```
loginWithFacebook(): void {
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider())
        .then(_ => this.navCtrl.setRoot('HomePage'))
        .catch(error => alert(error));
}

loginWithGoogle(): void {
    let provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login');
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
        .then(_ => this.navCtrl.setRoot('HomePage'))
        .catch((error) => alert(error));

}
```

Comment: Woudn't you be logged into two different accounts?

Comment: I want to implement it on web site so can I use angular /iconic

Comment: It is just an example, you can implement it in Angular.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using FirebaseUI. It takes care of all the edge cases for you and it is straightforward to use. There are situations where for example you sign in with Google and then sign in with Facebook using the same email. Account linking would be needed to merge both accounts.